# 0 file indexed after sonar.inclusion

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarQube Server 4.0, when I am running command sonar-runner on command prompt at project root path, it is working fine, it indexes files but when I am using sonar.inclusions=src/RicercaItemVO.java sonar works but it is not indexing any file. SonarQube runner version is 2.3

12:36:21.919 INFO  - Index files
12:37:00.309 INFO  - 0 files indexed

Does anyone having an idea?

Comment: How did you set `sonar.sources` property? If you set it to `src`, as the `sonar.inclusions` property is relative to the `sonar.sources` path, `sonar.inclusions` should be set to `RicercaItemVO.java`.

Comment: I am using it as

sonar.inclusions=src/RicercaItemVO.java
sonar.sources=/src
sonar.binaries=/build/classes

Also I tried

sonar.inclusions=/src/RicercaItemVO.java
sonar.sources=/src
sonar.binaries=/build/classes

and

sonar.inclusions=src/RicercaItemVO.java
sonar.sources=src
sonar.binaries=/build/classes

Comment: Hi David and Ann thanks a lot issue seems to be resolved, I removed /src from sonar.inclusions it is indexing file now. 15:45:38.040 INFO  - Index files 15:45:47.843 INFO  - 1 files indexed...but facing another issue now related to findbug jar --> 15:46:00.886 WARN  - Failed to load plugin for custom detector: /C:/Development/workspace/Four/.sonar/.sonartmp/plugins/findbugs/META-INF/lib/findbugs-2.0.2.jar

Comment: Good news! For your other issue about the FindBugs plugin, I advise you to open a new thread.

Comment: Thanks, sure, I am working on other issue, if it will not get resolved I will open a new thread for help. Thanks again